# Cannot connect to wifi modem when a LAN user is connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a small home network where computers are connected to a wifi modem using either LAN or wifi, but recently it has developed strange problem. When a PC is connected through LAN to this modem, no one can connect to it using wifi. Once I disconnect the LAN cable, wifi connections get established immediately.

What might be causing this problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that PC isn't using the SAME ip-address as the Wifi/router ? If that is the case the PC normally shouldn't be able to get on the internet itself when it is connected by LAN, but that isn't a 100% certain. I have seen (consumer-grade) routers that would do NAT even if the PC was using the routers LAN-side ip-address.

Comment: Thanks Tony. It is connected to another wifi router at the neighbours. I will check with them.

Comment: it was a cable issue